# Oscilloscope can't detect voltage and waveform

Tags: voltage, current, oscilloscope, generator, function

I am having a trouble with my research.

I am using a function generator to deliver electrical voltage to a wire and when I check it with the oscilloscope, it detects nothing (waveform, voltage.) Is it because the current did not flow to the wire? Can I use some signal amplifier like Juntek DPA-698 to overcome this problem? I am very new to this electrical stuff so any suggestion and recommendation really help me.

Here is the setup I made:

[image]

I am using a carbon electrode connected to the function generator to give electricity to the specimen. Then I use another carbon electrode on the specimen to detect the waveform and voltage, but in the scope shows nothing (I am using a square wave.)

Is there something wrong with the setup?

As asked in comments: I already try connecting the fun gen with the scope directly and the scope show the square waveform and the voltage which I set on the fun gen.

Comment: Schematic of Your setup would defenetly help.

Comment: Please give us a link to your function generator and oscilloscope, so everybody can try to help. Usually a scope can directly display fun gen's waveforms. You don't need any signal amplifier. (1) One suggestion to start troubleshooting is use the scope to display the sample waveform (usually a 1kHz square wave) located at the front panel of the scope. (2) Then read the fun gen user manual. Do you have any manual for the fun gen?

Comment: Your description of using a ***fun gen signal to output to a wire*** is a bit vague. Usually I output the signal to a resistor, say, 10Hz square wave to a 10k Ohm resistor. Or show us a photo of your hardware setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am sorry I still can't provide the setup. But in general I am trying to detect the voltage and waveform from the carbon electrode which I connected to the function generator using alligator clip. When I detect the electrode using the scope probe it does not show any result. I am using RIGOL DS1102Z-E (Scope) and DG812 (FG)

Comment: It sounds as though you have a short circuit somewhere and there is no voltage to measure. Try connecting the scope directly to the signal generator first.

Comment: This is too vague, we can only guess. Maybe you didn't manage to ground the probe.

Comment: Do you know how to use your scope, for example how to set the sensitivity (V/div), timebase, or how the trigger system works? Are you able to see other signals?

Comment: _" it detect nothing (waveform, voltage)"_ - what waveform and voltage were you expecting?

Comment: There are two wires coming from the function generator. One of them is a ground. There are also two coming from the scope. One of them is a ground. Keep in mind that the other wire of the scope measures voltages relative to ground. If you attach it to the ground of the function generator you will see nothing.

Comment: Measure the carbon resistance with a multimeter. Then work out what percentage of your signal you'll have when the source impedance is 50 ohms. Add the info into your question.

Comment: That's strange, even if shorted out function generators usually have a 50ohm output, so you should see *something* unless you load is *really* low impedance

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation, based on your rather vague description, is that the resistance of your carbon electrode is very low compared to the output resistance of your generator which is probably 50 ohms. Thus, little voltage will appear across the electrode. I suggest measuring the resistance between the 2 points that you are connecting to the generator.